# What is the product attribute for product ID?

Tags: magento2.3, attributes, xml, google-product-feeds

**Every product recieves a unique ID, shown on the left on the product page screenshot.
I do not choose this nunmber, the number is assigned by the system.**

**Now I am trying to create a pricefeed with XML template and I need to provide unique product ID in the pricefeed, however my own SKU is too long so I want to use Magentos product ID.**

**What is the actual internal magento 'attribute code' for the magento product ID to the left?**
I've checked [Product Export Attributes Reference](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/data-attributes-product.html) where this specific magento product ID isn't listed.

[image: screenshot magento product page]

Comment: The "product id" is auto-incremented in catalog_product_entity (see "entity_id")

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

The "product id" is an auto-incremented field created in catalog_product_entity table.

See

- entity_id in catalog_product_entity table

Answer (score 0):

Sort and sweet it's **entity_id**.

You can use that field for your mapping with xml.

You can check entity_ id field in catalog_product_entity table.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: you are welcome :) you can accept answer for helping another community member.